# Execute an excel macro from python in unix environment

Tags: python, excel, unix

Can anyone share any code snippet to execute an execl macro using python code in unix environment?

I tried using xlwings, but that doesn't support in unix environment.

Use Case: I have a pivot table report in excel with filter and using macro we want to change the filter value.

Comment: `xlwings` depends on the pywin32 library and Office software.

Comment: If it's an Excel Macro it would need to run in Excel right? So not an option in Unix. unless you are doing some thing with LibreOffice or other UNIX Office app. Maybe if you provide more detail of your ultimate aim a workable solution might be suggested.

Comment: We have generated reports in excel from Power BI dataset and the reports contains macros as well. Now through a automated process we want to schedule/generate the whole report and send that users. That is why looking to execute macros (which will change report input and save) from unix using python.

Comment: Just to be clear, you have open these excel reports that you generated from PowerBI datasets that contain macros in a unix OS and were able to run the macros in a unix OS?

Comment: @JNevill - Macros are written in standard VBA code. But I am trying to execute those from Unix environment.

Answer (score 3):

In a Unix environment, executing Excel macros can indeed be challenging because tools like [`xlwings`](https://www.xlwings.org/) are not supported.

However, you can try utilizing a combination of Python libraries and external applications to achieve this.
But you would need:

- a  virtualization of Windows application using [`Wine`](https://www.winehq.org/) for VBA Macro execution.
- something for reading/writing Excel files, like [`openpyxl`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

That means, you would have to install:

- Wine in your Unix environment (`sudo apt update`+`sudo apt install wine`).
  It will allow you to run Windows applications on Unix-like operating systems.
- a [Windows version of Python](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/) using Wine. You will run a script through this Python installation to trigger your macro.
- [pywin32](https://pbpython.com/windows-com.html) (in your *Windows* Python environment), the `win32com` library: `wine python -m pip install pywin32`
- `openpyxl` library (in your *Unix* Python environment) to read and manipulate Excel files (`pip install openpyxl`)

Create a Python script (named, for instance, `run_macro.py`) that will be executed in the Windows Python environment through Wine. That script should utilize `win32com` library to run the macro.

```py
import os
import sys
from win32com.client import DispatchEx

def run_excel_macro(file_path, macro_name):
    xl = DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
    xl.Workbooks.Open(file_path)
    xl.Application.Run(macro_name)
    xl.Application.Save()  # Save the changes
    xl.Application.Quit()  # Quit Excel
    del xl

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_excel_macro(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
```

Create a Python script `trigger_macro_unix.py` in your Unix environment to trigger the above `run_macro.py` script through Wine. You can use [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) to call Wine and execute the script:

```py
import subprocess

def call_macro_through_wine(file_path, macro_name):
    subprocess.run(["wine", "python", "path/to/run_macro.py", file_path, macro_name], check=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    call_macro_through_wine("path/to/excel_file.xlsm", "MacroName")
```

Now, you can execute the Unix Python script `trigger_macro_unix.py` to call your macro through Wine and the Windows Python environment:

```bash
python3 path/to/trigger_macro_unix.py
```

Do replace "`path/to/run_macro.py`", "`path/to/excel_file.xlsm`", and "`MacroName`" with your actual file paths and macro name.

Answer (score 2):

You are in a dead end. Excel VBA macros use the underlying Windows COM services to communicate with a true Excel process which in turn manipulate the file. Said differently, even in a true Windows system, you need a Microsoft Office installation for those macros to run, whatever the calling language.

I have personally experienced this problem on a Windows box with no Microsoft Office installed (only LibreOffice for licenses reason) where I could not execute my macros, despite a correct installation of pywin32.

The only possibility from Linux is to directly manipulate the Excel file with openpyxl... which is definitely not the same as using the Excel engine through VBA macros!